# Swift 3, Successfully passed data but var returns nil when used

Tags: ios, swift

So here is my code from VC1 and passing the data to VC2.

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        selectedArtist = artists[indexPath.item]
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "artistToArtSegue", sender: self)

    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "artistToArtSegue" {
            let artCollectionController = ArtCollectionController()
            artCollectionController.artist = selectedArtist
            artCollectionController.selectedArtist = selectedArtist
        }
    }
```

These codes here in VC2 will print the data

```
class ArtCollectionController: UICollectionViewController {

    var artist = Artist() {
        didSet{
            print(artist.artistId ?? "did not work")
            print(artist.name ?? "what name?")
        }
    }
    var selectedArtist = Artist()
```

but when I use the the variable in these following test codes in VC2. They return a nil.

```
func fetchArtForArtist() {
        guard let artistId = selectedArtist.artistId else {return}
        print(artistId)
        let fanRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("art_ref").child(artistId)
        fanRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
            let artId = snapshot.key
            print(artId)
//            let dataRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child(artId)
//            dataRef.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
//                let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject]
//                //let art =

//            }, withCancel: nil)
        }, withCancel: nil)

    }

@IBAction func testButton(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        print(selectedArtist.name ?? "no name")
        print(12345)
    }
 override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        selectedArtist = artist
        print(artist.name ?? "non")
        print(selectedArtist.artistId ?? "no id")

    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        fetchArtForArtist()
        selectedArtist = artist
        print(artist.name ?? "non")
        print(selectedArtist.artistId ?? "no id")


    }
```

Im doing this in storyBoard. Im even using 2 vars seeing if there is a difference.  I dont understand why the data is successfully passed to VC2 to a couple variables but when the variable is used it returns a nil. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "artistToArtSegue" {
        let artCollectionController = segue.destination as! ArtCollectionController
        artCollectionController.artist = selectedArtist
        artCollectionController.selectedArtist = selectedArtist
    }
}
```

try this, you are creating one more `ArtCollectionController` instead of passing data to segue one

Comment: you're a rockstar man! Quick and painless! I guess how I did it before was more for programmatic approach. It works in my other projects that are programmatic. THANK YOU SIR!

Comment: @ReyCerio No, the code you posted was simply wrong.  This bit: `let artCollectionController = ArtCollectionController()` creates a brand new instance of `ArtCollectionController` which will only exist inside the braces of the `if` statement. It will never be displayed to the screen, and has nothing to do with the `ArtCollectionController` that is about to be displayed. JuicyFruit's code is the way to get access to the view controller you are segueing to.

Comment: This answer is decent, but somewhat fragile. If you mess up your storyboard and forget to set  the view controller with identifier "artistToArtSegue " to have a class of `ArtCollectionController`, the force-cast will crash. Plus, it's fairly common to have a view controller segue to multiple different view controllers in different situations. In that case having `prepare(for:sender:)` use a switch statement lets you handle all those different destinations neatly.

Answer (score 4):

The other responses are good, but I prefer a slightly different approach:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    switch segue.destination {

    case let artCollectionController as ArtCollectionController:
        artCollectionController.artist = selectedArtist
        artCollectionController.selectedArtist = selectedArtist
    case let otherViewController as OtherViewController:
        //Code for some other case
    }
}
```

By using a switch statement, you have a `prepareForSegue` that will handle multiple different segues cleanly.

The `case let` construct is a cool trick that only executes that case if the variable in the switch can be case to the desired type. If it **can** be cast, it creates a local variable of the desired type.

I prefer deciding what code to execute based on the class of the destination view controller because it's less fragile than using the segue identifier. If you forget to set the segue identifier, or add a second segue later to the same type of view controller, or have a typo in the name of the identifier, that code won't work. If you have a typo in your class name, though, the compiler throws an error.

Answer (score 2):

Because you set the `artist` property on a new instance of `ArtCollectionController`, which is destroyed upon the exit of the `prepareForSegue` function:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "artistToArtSegue" {
        let artCollectionController = ArtCollectionController() // created
        artCollectionController.artist = selectedArtist
        artCollectionController.selectedArtist = selectedArtist
        // destroyed here
    }
}
```

Try this instead:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "artistToArtSegue",
        let artCollectionController = segue.destination as? ArtCollectionController
    {
        artCollectionController.artist = selectedArtist
        artCollectionController.selectedArtist = selectedArtist
    }
}
```

Comment: not sure if `if let` for `destination` is good practice here, your destination has to be `DestinationViewControllerForIdentifier` otherwise something is not right at all.

Comment: It's never a good practice to force cast (`as!`) unless you are sure it works. I've come across several mysterious crashes which turned out to be identifier that changed during subsequent code revisions

Comment: Thanks man, I'll accept JuicyFruit's answer as the answer though just because he posted first. Your answer is essentially the same as his so I'll +1 your answer. Though your answer does explain why I have to use `segue.destination` which gives me a better understanding of why my var loses its data. Thanks again.